# React Router V4 but on a different homepage in package.json... fix 404 not found?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

package.json

```
"name": "debate",
"homepage": "/debate", // I THINK THIS IS THE PROBLEM
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1"
}
```

App.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Route path='/thread/:pathParam?' component={Thread}/>
        <Route path='/post' component={Post}/>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

When I test the app on... [ http://localhost:3000/thread ] everything works perfectly well.

When I build the app for production and upload my files to my server, the directory [ http://www.example.com/debate/thread ] gives a 404 error saying "The requested URL /debate/thread/ was not found on this server."

```
The requested URL /debate/thread/ was not found on this server.
```

[ http://www.example.com/debate/ ] still works perfectly well.

I'm not sure how to get react-router-dom to recognize that we're actually on a sub-directory...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the `basename` property of the `BrowserRouter` object.

The documentation — 
[BrowserRouter.md](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/BrowserRouter.md)

So in production it should be:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/debate">
```

Or more realisitcally:

```
<BrowserRouter basename={ROUTE_BASENAME}>
```

And that `ROUTE_BASENAME` should resolve to `/` locally and to `/debate` on the server. You can use the [Webpack DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin) to handle that kind of variables.

Comment: I've updated it to *<BrowserRouter basename='/debate'>* but it's still not working. This looks like the exact thing I need though. You're completely correct about http://localhost:3000/debate/thread/543 versus http://localhost:3000/thread/543 where the *debate* directory should be optional on localhost. That's fine, I don't mind typing that in... but production still gives a 404.

Comment: Check whether the links generated with `<Link>` component actually include the `basename` provided. And an important thing — the page containing the `BrowserRouter` component must live on a page with URL starting with the same base prefix (`/debate`). Also make sure that the server is configured to server the same index.html for all those nested pages

Comment: Wait, hold on... it's working... but only if I *don't* input the URL on the address bar and hit enter. It works fine if I design the application through links alone, but what if a user wants to share a specific link rather than going through the splash-page of the website. Further, a user can't even refresh the page. You set me on the exact right path.

Comment: SOLUTION HERE: I found hash history instead of BrowserHistory working brilliantly, thank you so much for the help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually

Comment: Sure, hash history makes it way simpler, I've thought that the URLs without the `#` is a must for you. Btw, given that it worked fine for you until you try to refresh the page — the only problem left is to set up the server to return the same html page for all the pages in the `/debate` directory.

Comment: Just to add a bit more information... Google SEO doesn't seem to have a problem with React... but it does have a problem with React Router... https://medium.freecodecamp.org/using-fetch-as-google-for-seo-experiments-with-react-driven-websites-914e0fc3ab1

Comment: In case of create-react-app you can also try `basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}` - PUBLIC_URL env is derived from homepage in package.json.